# cascade delete the child record of the table

Tags: yii

I have table with column id, name and parentid

relation function in model:

```
 'location_parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Location', 'parentid'),
 'location_children' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Location', 'parentid', 'order' => 'id ASC'),
```

delete action in controller:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

Requirement:

Here, If I delete the record with `id = 1`, then the row with `parentid = 1` is also required to delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your model override the `beforeDelete` method to delete all child records recursively before deleting the parent i.e.

```
public function beforeDelete(){
    foreach($this->location_children as $c)
        $c->delete();
    return parent::beforeDelete();
}
```

Be sure to wrap the initial delete call in a transaction to ensure all or none of the records are deleted.

You could also just use `CDbCommand` to perform the deletion.

Comment: I would do it in `afterDelete()`! The reason is, that the delete command could fail in the DB for some reason. In which case you probably don't want to delete the related child records. Whereas `afterDelete()` only gets executed, if the deletion was successful.

Comment: If you do it in afterDelete, your database may complain because you will be deleting records that has foreign key records.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
              //delete location _children 

 foreach( $this->loadModel($id)->location_children as $c)
         $c->delete();

              //delete location_parent

 foreach( $this->loadModel($id)->location_parent as $c)
         $c->delete();

            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

or you can also user `deleteall()` to delete all records of specific id

```
AssociatedModel::model()->deleteAll("parent_id ='" . $id . "'");
```