# Yii delete active records with relationship

Tags: php, yii

I have two tables:

```
users{
id
username
password
}

person{
id
fname
lname
user_id
}
```

and relation in User model:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'person'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Person', 'user_id'),
    );
}
```

In tutorial there was said I can delete both by writting in user controller:

```
$this->loadModel($id)->person->delete();
```

but it deletes only person record in db.

and if I write:

```
$this->loadModel($id)->with('person')->delete();
```

This deletes only  user record in db.

How can I delete both using these relations or changing them perhaps?

Of course I could write that in 3 lines:

```
$user=$this->loadModel($id);
Person::model()->findByPk($user->person_id)->delete();
$user->delete();
```

and it would delete both.

Comment: Put the persons delete in the `beforeDelete()` of the User model.
Note: you must use `$person->delete()` for this to work, not `delete($criteria)` or anything with mass deletion.

Comment: Whoops I meant `$user->delete()` not $person.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cascade delete the child record of the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248852/cascade-delete-the-child-record-of-the-table)

Answer (score 3):

Yii has no logic implemented to automatically handle DB write operations on child relations. So its up to you how to achieve your target. There are different ways:

1. Use your DB and define a `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint on the foreign key column. No additional Yii logic is required.
2. Overwrite the `beforeDelete()` `beforeSave()` `afterDelete()` `afterSave()` functions of `CActiveRecord` or use the event system (see [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/327/events-explained)) to implement your logic inside your model.
3. Use your controller and do the work manually.

I would always use the first way (1.) and implement DB constraints. But sometimes it is necessary to process some logic before delete a DB record. Then I would choose the second way (2.) maybe in combination with the first one.

To implement all the logic inside your controller (3.) isn't really a good code style except you are sure that the implemented code isn't needed at another part of your project.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In User controller:

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
  $model = $this->findModel($id);

  foreach($model->persons as $person)
    $person->delete();

  $model->delete();
  return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

You must have a property dependence called 'persons' in User model:

```
* @property Person[] $persons

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPersons()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Person::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually overwrite the `onDelete` or do the following.

```
if($user->delete()){
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand("Delete from userProfile where user_id={$model->id}")->execute();
}
```