# delete related records in yii (3 levels)

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to delete yii records if parent record is deleted . i have searched a lot about this like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507301/yii-delete-active-records-with-relationship), but my problem is different.

I have 3 tables:

1. Tasks
2. Taskusn (task_id)
3. TaskUsnItems (usn_id)

Now tasks is related to tasksusn with `task_id` and tasksusnitems are related to taskusn with `usn_id`. 
My model is

**Tasks.php**

```
public function afterdelete()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition ="task_id=".$this->id; 
    TasksUsn::model()->deleteAll($criteria);
}
```

This is working very well. and deleting all associated records.

**TasksUsn.php**

```
public function beforedelete()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition ="usn_id=".$this->id;  
    TaskUsnItems::model()->deleteAll($criteria);
}
```

This is not working . I tried `beforedelete` and `afterdelete` but no effect. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you sure that the models name and their attributes are correct? your third table is `TaskUsnItems` while in TasksUsn.php you are trying to delete from `PresetUsnitems` model ?!

Comment: i am so sory .that was a mistake in question . both are same