# Yii2 Dynamic forms action update get error

Tags: php, yii2

I have two models in my Yii2 application :

```
  Racks(rackID,rowID,...)
  RackObjects(rack_objectID,rackID,objectID,...)
```

In my racksController I have :

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $modelsRackObjects = $model->rackObjects;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsRackObjects, 'rack_objectID', 'rack_objectID');
        $modelsRackObjects = Racks::createMultiple(RackObjects::classname(), $modelsRackObjects);
        Racks::loadMultiple($modelsRackObjects, Yii::$app->request->post());
        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsRackObjects, 'rack_objectID', 'rack_objectID')));

        // validate all models
        $valid = $model->validate();
        $valid = Racks::validateMultiple($modelsRackObjects) && $valid;

        if ($valid) {
            $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                    if (!empty($deletedIDs)) {
                        Racks::deleteAll(['rackID' => $deletedIDs]);
                    }
                    foreach ($modelsRackObjects as $modelRackObjects) {
                        $modelRackObjects->rackID = $model->rackID;
                        if (! ($flag = $modelRackObjects->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->rackID]);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsRackObjects' => (empty($modelsRackObjects)) ? [new RackObjects] : $modelsRackObjects
    ]);
}
```

And in my "Racks Model" I have :

```
public static function createMultiple($modelClass, $multipleModels = [])
{
    $model    = new $modelClass;
    $formName = $model->formName();
    $post     = Yii::$app->request->post($formName);
    $models   = [];

    if (! empty($multipleModels)) {
        $keys = array_keys(ArrayHelper::map($multipleModels, 'rack_objectID', 'rack_objectID'));
        $multipleModels = array_combine($keys, $multipleModels);
    }

    if ($post && is_array($post)) {
        foreach ($post as $i => $item) {
            if (isset($item['rack_objectID']) && !empty($item['rack_objectID']) && isset($multipleModels[$item['rack_objectID']])) {
                $models[] = $multipleModels[$item['rack_objectID']];
            } else {
                $models[] = new $modelClass;
            }
        }
    }

    unset($model, $formName, $post);

    return $models;
}
```

When I update the racks form and change some rackObjects I get this error :

Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

What is wrong in my action update???

I changed my codes thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844851/yii2-dynamic-forms-action-update-get-error/39848908#39848908) and now when I update records the child table (rackObjects) duplicated and old records was not deleted!! any idea?

Comment: There's a record in other table that is related to Racks.

Comment: I knew that! but my question is how to change the codes to handle SQLSTATE[23000] exception?

Comment: Then use cascade delete, refer to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248852/cascade-delete-the-child-record-of-the-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248852/cascade-delete-the-child-record-of-the-table)

Comment: I added beforeDelete() function to my controller but nothing happened! SQLSTATE[23000] exception

Comment: No, not in controller, add it to model. [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeDelete()-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeDelete()-detail)

Comment: I added this codes to my model :

`public function beforeDelete(){ foreach($this->rackObject as $c)  {         $c->delete();  }  return Racks::beforeDelete(); } `
but my problem not solved

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

`deleteAll()` will not raise the `beforeDelete` event. You should loop through:

```
$racks = Rack::findAll(['rackID' => $deletedIDs]);
foreach($racks as $rack) {
  $rack->delete();
}
```

And in `Rack` model, assuming you have `hasMany` relationship with `RackObjects`

```
public function beforeDelete() {
  if (parent::beforeDelete()) {
    foreach($this->rackObjects as $rackObj) {
      $rackObj->delete();
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I added your suggested codes and my integrity problem solved! Thanks but when I update and change some rackObjects records nothing changed and returned to view! What is problem?

Comment: Maybe it's already deleted because it's related to Racks. When you delete the racks the rack objects that are related will also be deleted

Comment: And now when I press update it's duplicate children (rackObjects)!! I'm confusing!!!